# How can I use an OptionBox to drive the value of a ComboBox with selective values from my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I am searching for a method that can easily link selective values from my worksheet in a combo box list based on the option box that is selected. I am new to VBA and I am wondering if I am getting the syntax wrong.
I think my method is correct but I keep getting an error when the option is selected: Compile Error: Sub of Function not defined. This error exists when the Private Sub option buttons are run. If I delete that part of the code, then my ComboBox list is empty, but I get no error message..
I am used to working with JavaScript, so calling functions is very common, maybe not with VBA?

```
Dim myTable As Range

'Updated by Extendoffice 2018/1/30
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B8")
    If OptionButton1 = True And OptionButton2 = False Then

       Me.ComboBox1.List = myTable.Range("A2:A3").Value
    ElseIf OptionButton2 = True And OptionButton1 = False Then
     Me.ComboBox1.List = myTable.Range("A5:A8").Value
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
Call UserForm
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
Call UserForm
End Sub
```

[This is the form outcome when the option box is selected without including the last 6 lines of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQxn7.png)

Comment: `Call UserForm` should maybe be `UserForm.Show`   Also note that the output of Range() is *relative* to the object it's called on.  So  `ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B8")` is A2:B8 as expected, but in your code above, `myTable.Range("A2:A3")` is actually A3:A4, because the top-left of myTable is A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your userform Image, I've replicated your form with `UserForm1` and all default names for all controls.

If you move your `If...Then` statements to your `Optionbutton_Change()` events, you will populate your lists.

Per [Microsoft Documentation about the `Initialize` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event):

> The Initialize event is typically used to prepare an application or UserForm for use.Variables are assigned initial values, and controls may be moved or resized to accommodate initialization data.

So it's not to update data once you have loaded the form already.

I've tested the following on a new workbook with dummy data in `A1:A10` for the first option button list and `B1:B10` for the second optionbutton list.

**Note:** this is all contained in the `UserForm` code module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim TargetCell As Range

If Me.OptionButton1 = True Then
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear '<~~ This removes the previous list items from the combobox.
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" '<~~ Removes the default value added at initialization. 
    Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem TargetCell.Value
    Next TargetCell
End If

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
If Me.OptionButton2 = True Then
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear '<~~ This removes the previous list items from the combobox.
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" '<~~ Removes the default value added at initialization. 
    Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")
    For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem TargetCell.Value
    Next TargetCell
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 

Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Select an OptionButton below..."

End Sub
```

### Key changes in my code to yours:

- I'm updating my `ComboBox` list in the `OptionButton_Change()` event handler.
- I haven't evaluated if one is `True` and the other is `False` as OptionButtons can only have one selected at any one time within their group.

  - When you add them to a `Frame`, they are automatically grouped separate to Optionbuttons outside of the `Frame` ([see here stating they are mutually exclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/frame-control)).
- I've used dummy data in a range not related to your worksheet - but you just need to change the references to your worksheets and your ranges.
- I've included `Me.ComboBox1.Clear` as the first statement executed if the `OptionButton` in question is selected, as this clears the list that may already be populated

  - If you omit this and the user clicks `OptionButton1` populating the first range of values in the ComboBox and then they click `OptionButton2` you would end up with your second range of values being added to the bottom of the list, after the already populated first range of values.
- I've included a default value in the `ComboBox` added in the `Initialize` event. *This is not mandatory.*

### Screenshot examples of the forms behaviour:

Dummy Data on Sheet1:

[image: Dummy data on sheet1]

First opened:

[image: UserForm first opened.]

OptionButton1 list: ______________________  OptionButton2 list: _______________________

[image: Option button 1 list]  [image: Option button 2 list]

---

You could write the entire thing into a function (or subroutine) and call *that* in the way you are trying to call the `Initialize` event.

Here's an example subroutine:

```
Public Sub ChangeMyComboBoxList()

Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim TargetCell As Range

If UserForm1.OptionButton1 = True Then
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Clear '<~~ This removes the previous list items from the combobox.
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "" '<~~ Removes the default value added at initialization.
    Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem TargetCell.Value
    Next TargetCell
ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True Then
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Clear '<~~ This removes the previous list items from the combobox.
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "" '<~~ Removes the default value added at initialization.
    Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")
    For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
        UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem TargetCell.Value
    Next TargetCell
End If

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()

ChangeMyComboBoxList '<~~ Call is not required

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()

ChangeMyComboBoxList '<~~ Call is not required

End Sub
```

Comment: Samuel, I appreciate your feedback. I did not think about it, the "initialize" setup would conflict with assigned values. Aside from that I see your approach is more modular than mine. I like your "update" feature to what I was trying to do. Encapsulating the code within my OptionButtons subroutines has fixed the problem. I will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks much!